# How to fire the HTML form's onsubmit event?

Tags: delphi, mshtml, twebbrowser

I'm trying to fire the HTML form's `onsubmit` event from a Delphi application using MSHTML. I've tried to use `IHTMLFormElement::submit` and `IHTMLDocument4::FireEvent` methods but none of them fired the form's `onsubmit` event.

Here's my first attempt:

```
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument4;
  FormElement: IHTMLFormElement;
begin
  Document := (WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument4);
  FormElement := (Document as IHTMLDocument2).Forms.item('form', 0) as IHTMLFormElement;
  FormElement.submit;
end;
```

And here's my second attempt:

```
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument4;
  FormElement: IHTMLFormElement;
begin
  Document := (WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument4);
  FormElement := (Document as IHTMLDocument2).Forms.item('form', 0) as IHTMLFormElement;
  Document.FireEvent('onSubmit', 'null');
  Document.FireEvent('onSubmit', FormElement.onsubmit);
end;
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fire the HTML form's `onsubmit` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt failed because the [`IHTMLFormElement::submit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method does not fire the `onsubmit` event, the reference for this method says the following:

> The IHTMLFormElement::submit method does not invoke the
>   HTMLFormElementEvents::onsubmit event handler.

Your next attempt failed because you were trying to fire the event on the document element (imagine the decision that this element would have to do if there was more than one child element having this event attached). Except that you were passing wrong parameters. Try something like this (just don't forget to add proper error handling into your production code):

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Empty: OleVariant;
  EventObj: OleVariant;
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;
  FormElement: IHTMLElement3;
begin
  // get the document interface reference
  Document := (WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2);
  // generate an event object to pass event context information
  EventObj := (Document as IHTMLDocument4).CreateEventObject(Empty);
  // get the form element and fire the event
  FormElement := Document.forms.item('form', NULL) as IHTMLElement3;
  FormElement.FireEvent('onsubmit', EventObj);
end;
```

Here is an example HTML to play with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form name="form" onsubmit="submitForm()">
         <input type="submit">
      </form>
      <script>
         function submitForm() {
             alert("The form was submitted!");
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast as IHTMLElement and call Click method.

```
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument4;
  FormElement: IHTMLFormElement;
begin
  Document := (WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument4);
  FormElement := (Document as IHTMLDocument2).Forms.item('form', 0) as IHTMLElement;
  FormElement.Click;
end;
```

Comment: Click ? Why would you click the form ? That makes less than no sense.

Comment: That's what you would do if you were doing it manually instead of programmatically.

Comment: No, you would `submit` it, not `click`.